# The development server returned response error code:500(React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am getting The development server returned response error code:500 after adding react navigation libraries, any solution

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How do you add `react-navigation`?  Is `react-navigation` in your node modules?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this error by following command :

```
npm i react-navigation-stack --save
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to import `createStackNavigator` and `createAppContainer` separately and you will get that module in react-navigation and react-navigation-stack package

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

> createStackNavigator is a function that returns a React component. It
>   takes a route configuration object and, optionally, an options object
>
> createAppContainer is a function that returns a React component to
>   take as a parameter the React component created by the
>   createStackNavigator

Referance [React Native Guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/hello-react-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was importing `createAppContainer` and `createStackNavigator`  from `react-navigation-stack` but solved it by making them seperate

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error my first install not complete due to new connectivity
i delete folder and install again make sure your net connectivity is good .
and install again
It's up to you where you are installing your app
if you install app mobile device
then see this link
https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device